# Am I really tracking my subdomain?

Tags: google-analytics, dns

This is very similar to my last question, but now I'm putting a different angle on it.

Could it be that because of my DNS configuration, I'm not able to track traffic using filters?

On my main site I'm able to see referral sites (including my partners site).

I have the following domains:

```
www.mysite.com  
partner1.mysite.com
```

Both `www.mysite.com` and `partner1.mysite.com` uses the same www directory. The only difference is that I change the top and bottom section to display my partners logo and colors.

My partner has the following subdomain:

```
mysite.partner.com
```

My partner has configured the DNS to have `mysite.partner.com` point to `partner1.mysite.com`.

[image]

The reason for this is to have users believe they are surfing my partners website, when they are in fact surfing my website.

So in stead of my URL showing up in the browser, they see my partners URL.

This works fine and now I wanted to use Google Analytics to track traffic from my partner. I followed the [initial guide](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55524). I Added a new profile and added a filter to this:

> Filter type: include
>   Filter field: Host name
>   Filter pattern: partner1\.mysite\.no
>   Case sensetive: No

But no traffic is registered. I've tried various alternatives and I'm not getting any results.

Comment: You should post this same question in the Analytics forums http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!forum/analytics

Answer (score 1):

This may seem an obvious point but you'll need to check that your partners site has the  same google analytics tracking code as yours. If they do not then you won't be able to track the traffic to their site.

To do this go to their page, right click and view source, search for 'gaq' and check that the UA number in the google code is the same as your sites.

As long as they have the same code you should be able to be track their activity. Also it may be worth checking you are using the google analytics code that is created for sub domains

Within Analytics go to admin, click through the properties to your website and then view 'tracking code' and make sure your code has the subdomain line added.

Hopefully this may help.